# Populating set of enums based on booleans

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have a set: for argument's sake, let's call it `fruitBasket: Set[Fruit]`

The `Fruit` enum has values like `Apple`, `Pear` and `Orange`

I'd to populate `fruitBasket` with:

- `Apple` if boolean `hasApple` is true
- `Pear` if boolean `hasPear` is true,
- `Orange` if boolean `hasOrange` is true

`fruitBasket` would contain `Apple`, `Pear` and `Orange` if all three booleans are true, for example

What's the most syntactically neat way of doing this in Scala, please?

The real-life use case is a Form mapping in Play that handles checkboxes. I'm not a fan of my current implementation, which feels clumsy:

```
var modes = Set[ExchangeMode]()
if (exchangeModeL) modes += LenderHosts
if (exchangeModeD) modes += DropOffToBorrower
if (exchangeModeP) modes += AtPublicPlace
modes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you prefer for comprehensions and pattern matching tuples:

```
for {
  (b, v) <- Set(hasApple->Apple, hasPear->Pear, hasOrange->Orange) if b
} yield v
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
val modes = Map(
  LenderHosts       -> exchangeModeL, 
  DropOffToBorrower -> exchangeModeD, 
  AtPublicPlace     -> exchangeModeP
) filter (_._2) keySet
```